# Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Getting an error as :

```
Type '{ store: Store<CombinedState<{ user: User; }>, AnyAction>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Property 'store' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.(2322)

with my `react typescript` app. do not know what is missed out here. please any one help me?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jdycn4?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Just move store to `Privider`

```
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
```

Comment: getting another issue as : `Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'`

Comment: Update `rootReducers` in the `configureStore` to `rootReducer` (without `s`)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.